# heroku worker task memory quota exceeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memory-management, heroku, worker

I have a rails app deployed on heroku. We have ONE worker (jobs:work) which serially creates seven manager objects (one for each task) and runs methods on them in an infinite loop. This is what the main code looks like (the essential part of it anyway):

```
loop do
  begin
    Manager.subclasses.each do |manager_klass|
      manager_klass.new.process
    end
  #exception handling here
  end
  sleep(1)
end
```

None of the tasks do something like Model.all or such. I've read many articles about leaks and bloats in ruby and avoided most of them.

Heroku logs for my worker includes:
R14 - Memory quota exceeded;

This starts showing up after approximately 3 hours of worker running (which is substantial proof of a memory leak/memory buildup).

I've tried memprof (doesn't work for ruby 1.9), bleak_house (shoes irrelevant information) and other gems which use linux commands to log memory snapshots (which wont work with heroku).

I have looked all the answers on stackoverflow regarding this, none help.

Any ideas on my specific case of seven managers working within a single job?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for looking at your memory  usage: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics.  Also see this https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/3/19/log2viz  Together they should give you confirmation on your memory leak.

Would a different version of Ruby help?

Also: why do you create "sub-workers", so to speak?  Isn't your worker being fully utilised?  Do you really need to process 7 jobs concurrently like that (instead of having more workers).

Comment: Thanks Jon.

Neither of the articles you mention will help me since they tell the overall usage of RAM. The leak is somewhere inside one of the task_managers in the worker.

My recent finding is that memory accumulates even on one task running in an infinite loop, the fewer sub-workers, the less rapid is accumulation, but still exists.

I need to use 'sub-workers' (cool name) because i have 8 tasks running, 4 of which need to run after every 2 to 5 seconds, and I cant afford 4 separate workers running continuously.

I'm using ruby 1.9, should be ok.